# Is it possible to use OCaml in embedded mode?

Tags: interop, ocaml

Some time ago I emerged for myself that Guile and Racket can be embedded and be called right from any C++ application.

Can OCaml work like this?

Comment: I'd guess not. OCaml was designed as a compiled language, so it's not really intended to be used like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Embedded O'Caml Toplevel](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~capel/eng/toplevel/toplevel.html) done by Clément Capel. It's the result of a summer internship so it wasn't updated since 2004.

Otherwise, there is [ocamlmklib](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-311/manual032.html#toc137).

Comment: +1 for ocamlmklib, which the OP's comment makes clear is what he is looking for.

Comment: ocamlmklib has nothing to do with embedding OCaml. It is a wrapper around the linker to create mixed C-OCaml libraries.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the OCaml toplevel as a library. It is part of the official OCaml distribution and up-to-date. See toploop.mli in OCaml sources for the interface. It is officially only available in bytecode, but there is experimental support for native code.

If you plan to redistribute your application, be aware that the toplevel library (and the compiler itself) are under a more restrictive license (modified QPL) than the standard library and runtime (modified LGPL).